# Select latest records by datetime field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How could i select the latest records by datetime of an SQL Server?

Here is the pseudo-code...

```
SELECT Records 
  FROM MyTable 
 WHERE current time >= (CurrentTime - 2 minutes)
```

Supposing the current Time is 10:25:39 pm

```
26/10/2009 10:25:39 pm
26/10/2009 10:25:00 pm
26/10/2009 10:24:53 pm
26/10/2009 10:24:19 pm
26/10/2009 10:23:58 pm
26/10/2009 10:14:56 pm
26/10/2009 10:12:56 pm
```

the SQL query should return these records...

```
26/10/2009 10:25:39 pm
26/10/2009 10:25:00 pm
26/10/2009 10:24:53 pm
26/10/2009 10:24:19 pm
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Real code:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE currentTime >= DATEADD(n, -2,  GETDATE())
ORDER BY currentTime DESC
```

Comment: +1 for not putting the DateAdd function on the column! I always love queries that are mindful of potential index use (and I see this 'mess up' happen more than I care for).

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
WHERE t.currenttime BETWEEN DATEADD(mi, -2, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
ORDER BY t.currenttime DESC
```

References:

- [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)
- [BETWEEN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx)